# Why do I have 2 drives with the same used space?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, ssd

this is a weird one. I just bought a 2nd hand macbook retina and turns out that when I re-installed macOS, the storage dialog showed up a 2nd drive. The very first thought was that the main drive is a 500gb SSD and its partitioned in 2, so I went to disk utility and there where listed as two different drives. I didn't get a picture of it, but continued with the process and now with a couple of days of using the MBP I can see the two drives have almost identical used space, like a mirror.

All apps and OS where installed in the very first of the list, "Macintosh HD". But well Im going to leave you some screenshots so you can see better what's going on.

Thank you a lot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Those are my `diskutil list` results. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: 'HD 2' is *disk1s1* while 'Macintosh HD' is *disk1s5*.  Looks like one physical disk to me.  Can you edit in results of `diskutil list` (typed into terminal) to your question.

Comment: @lx07 Thanks bro. I just added the results.

Comment: So both are in same APFS container (your disk is 250GB).  Some [Copy on Write](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/06/23/what-is-copy-on-write-and-how-is-it-good/) thing is going on here - 'HD 2' doesn't really contain 150GB just links to 'Macintosh HD'.  Probably you can delete one or the other but I'm not sure which or how to do that safely so best wait for input from someone who does.

Comment: @lx07 Now with that scheme makes a lot of sense cause both are disk1 right? As you suggest I will not do anything until future update with previous backup hahaha. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Yes - disk1 is a fake disk (or synthesized if you prefer) which is stored in partition 2 on the only real physical disk you have (disk0).  All those 'APFS Volumes' that you see are stored in the same partition (or container) on your 250GB SSD.  Until someone who knows about merging volumes I'd ignore it.  But your question is an interesting one for sure.